# Unable to use same SQL Server table for multiple inserts and updates inside C# dbtransaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Problem with using single SQL Server table for multiple inserts and updates inside a C# dbtransaction.

Here are steps:

1. Started transaction in try block.
2. I have inserted a row into the SQL Server table using a stored procedure in a transaction which returns inserted ID
3. I have to update a column of above inserted row
4. I have to commit if success else rollback in catch if fails

Problem is that after inserting row it doesn't update as it gives timeout error on update (as I think it locks a table after insert).

How to update then after insert?

Here is my code:

```
using (var transaction = cnctn.BeginTransaction())
{
      try 
      {
         var ID = InsertInEmployeeTable(Employee);   // inserted successfully
         var Status = UpdateInEmployeeTable(ID,"Description");   // here timeout error happens
         transaction.Commit();
      } 
      catch(SqlException sqlError) 
      {
         transaction.Rollback();
      }
}
```

Comment: Without the code from the two calls for Insert and Update any answer is just a wild guess

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var transaction = cnctn.BeginTransaction())
{
      try 
      {
         var ID = InsertInEmployeeTable(Employee); //inserted succesfully
     var Status = UpdateInEmployeeTable(ID,"Description"); //Here timeout error
         transaction.Commit();
      } 
      catch(SqlException sqlError) 
      {try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                // a closed connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
            }
      }

}
```